# Meteor: Deploy to Own Server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, deployment, meteor

It turns out that deploying to some generic VPS is a very different experience from `meteor deploy`. I have it nearly sussed out, but being a Mongo n00b, I am having trouble with one thing: OpLog tailing. Here's the information so far:

Distro: Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)

```
$ mongod --version
db version v2.4.6
$ node --version
v0.10.33
```

I am using Meteor 1.0. and Passenger 4.0.53.

The good news is that changing to the deploy directory (I deployed as a bundle) and doing:

```
$ node bundle/main.js
```

lets me access the app on port 3000, but in development mode, hence not tailing the OpLog (I think).

So after a bunch of fits and starts, I rigged up Passenger with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sc.mywebapp.com
   DocumentRoot /home/deploy/meteor_apps/mywebapp/public
   PassengerStickySessions On
   SetEnv MONGO_URL mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/meteor
   SetEnv MONGO_OPLOG_URL mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/local
   SetEnv ROOT_URL http://sc.mywebapp.com

   # Set these ONLY if your app is a Meteor bundle!
   PassengerAppType node
   PassengerStartupFile bundle/main.js
   PassengerAppRoot /home/deploy/meteor_apps/mywebapp
</VirtualHost>
```

I had to add these to the bare metal httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.53/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.53
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p484/ruby
 PassengerNodejs /usr/local/bin/node
</IfModule>
```

Now the good news is that Passenger is *trying*. But because it is in production mode, it wants to tail the OpLog. And I get the following error:

```
Error: $MONGO_OPLOG_URL must be set to the 'local' database of a Mongo replica set
```

So, remembering that I'm a MongoDB N00b, what the heck do I have to do the get a local database of a Mongo replica set? This will be a small, low-traffic site initially -- it may grow, but I just want to get the initial deploy behind me.

What are the magic steps?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

The magic steps are having the correct user priv's, and providing the `authSource` parameter in your oplog connection string.

Create your user (MongoDB 2.4):

```
$ mongo -u YourExistingAdminUserName -p YourExistingAdminPassword 127.0.0.1/admin
cluster:PRIMARY> db.addUser({user: "oplogger", pwd: "PasswordForOplogger", roles: [], otherDBRoles: {local: ["read"]}})
```

Create your user (MongoDB 2.6+):

```
$ mongo -u YourExistingAdminUserName -p YourExistingAdminPassword 127.0.0.1/admin
cluster:PRIMARY> db.createUser({user: "oplogger", pwd: "PasswordForOplogger", roles: [{role: "read", db: "local"}]})
```

Then set your oplog URL:

```
MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://oplogger:PasswordForOplogger@127.0.0.1/local?authSource=admin
```

[Extra details are in the Meteor Wiki Oplog Driver article.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is where my mongodb n00b part comes in. I have mongo working as a stand-alone single db. For production, I need it to be clustered but on a single machine. I see by your prompt `cluster:PRIMARY>` you have a cluster. How is that accomplished? Isn't that something every production Meteor deploy will need to do?

Comment: Yeah, it' a replica-set (not sharded, as meteor doesn't support DB level sharding). Try http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/ for a guide, or https://mongolab.com/plans/pricing/ but it's a little expensive as you'll need a dedicated host to get oplog access ($180/month +)

Comment: @NathanM this tutorial(docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set fo) says maintain mongod instances on seperate machines. Is there a way to do that in a single machine? I saw there is a way to convert a standalone db to replica set but not recommended in production.

Comment: @YujunWu you can just start a single `mongod` instance with the `--replSet` option. It wont be very useful, but it will work.

Comment: I cannot believe how long I was missing that stupid OPLOG_URL setting. Once I enabled it and setup the user correctly.... blazing fast. Thank you.